# Problem running python script using TPU on VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

I created TPU and VM instance with same name via cloud console(not ctpu, gcloud).
When I check tpu on VM with command 
`gcloud compute tpus list`
I get my TPU READY.

But when I run python script:

`from tensorflow.contrib.cluster_resolver import TPUClusterResolver
tpu_grpc_url = TPUClusterResolver(tpu="v3-nonpre", zone="us-central1-a").get_master()`

It says `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/red-splice-230206/locations/us-central1-a/nodes/v3-nonpre?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

What should I do more to get the required authentication?

Comment: Can you share the gcloud commands that you used for creating the TPU and the VM instance? It appears that you may not have specified the right scopes.

Comment: I used cloud console to create TPU and VM instances. And I found the solution - I made the instance name same as my account name. And google cloud automatically configured correctly.